# Main method not found in class

Tags: java, compiler-errors, awt, japplet

```java
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

class Ball {

    int x, y, radius, dx, dy;
    Color BallColor;

    public Ball(int x, int y, int radius, int dx, int dy, Color bColor) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
        BallColor = bColor;
    }

}

public class Bounce extends Applet implements Runnable {

    Ball redBall;

    public void init() {
        redBall = new Ball(250, 80, 50, 2, 4, Color.red);
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(redBall.BallColor);
        setBackground(Color.pink);
        g.fillOval(redBall.x, redBall.y, redBall.radius, redBall.radius);
        g.drawLine(150, 400, 50, 500);
        g.drawLine(150, 400, 450, 400);
        g.drawLine(50, 500, 350, 500);
        g.drawLine(450, 400, 350, 500);
        g.drawRect(50, 500, 20, 100);
        g.drawRect(330, 500, 20, 100);
        g.drawLine(450, 400, 450, 500);
        g.drawLine(430, 500, 450, 500);
        g.drawLine(430, 500, 430, 420);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                displacementOperation(redBall);
                Thread.sleep(20);
                repaint();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void displacementOperation(Ball ball) {
        if (ball.y >= 400 || ball.y <= 0) {
            ball.dy = -ball.dy;
        }
        ball.y = ball.y + ball.dy;
    }

}
```

When I compile and run the code it says that the main method is not found in the class Bounce, please define the method as public static void main(String[] args). I do not know how to fix this would much appreciate if someone could point out what's wrong. Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have a class with a main method?

Comment: Read the "Getting started" guide (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html). You should know how a basic hello world program looks like and how to launch it before doing graphics with Java?

Comment: You're trying to run an Applet from the command line. Although this can be done, you need to add a main method. Applets don't have to have main methods.

Comment: @JBNizet creating a separate HTML did the trick no need of a main method.

Comment: You should still know those basics, even if you're only doing applets for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this Applet on applet enabled browser. The applet is initiated with following method.

```
public void init() // This method works as like main.
```

You just need to configure applet tag on html page to run this code.

```
<applet  code   = "Bounce.class"
    width   = "500"
    height  = "300">
</applet>
```